# frielndy url with GET form

Tags: html, forms, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

Im trying to make friendly url form my search result
right now my form look like this

```
<form action="/index.php" method=get id="wyszukaj">
    <input type="hidden" name=metoda value=search>
    <input type=text id="project" name=nazwa size=10 placeholder="Wpisz nazwę szukanej rośliny"  />
    <input type="hidden" id="project-id" />

    <a id="loop-icon" onclick="wyszukaj_submit();"></a>
</form>
```

When I type "borowka" and hit search button, page shows link:

**`index.php?metoda=szukaj&nazwa=borowka`**

But I want to produce link like that **`/search/borowka`**

How can I do that?
A addes this line to htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?metoda=search&nazwa=$1
```

and if I type **`/search/borowka`** direct in address bar, it work fine
I cant firure out redirect to **`/search/borowka`** from htaccess

Anybody can help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to tweak this a little depending on how you want to handle or translate szukaj to search... not sure if you intend metda to be fixed value or dynamic, but try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?metoda=(?:[^&\s]+)&nazwa=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /search/%1? [R,L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?metoda=search&nazwa=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) It works
I added this to htaccess
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?metoda=(?:[^&\s]+)&nazwa=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /szukaj/%1? [R,L]
RewriteRule ^szukaj/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?metoda=szukaj&nazwa=$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the first thing about PHP, but one thing you could do is use JavaScript to do what you want. You could, for instance, bind a JS function to your form's onsubmit event, and have that function build the URL the way you want and redirect the user to this URL, no?